# "Fig. x depicts" vs. "As depicted in Fig. x" in scientific publications

Tags: grammar, writing-style, active-voice

My boss doesn't like it, if I use phrases like "Fig. x depicts" or "Fig. x shows" in scientific publications and wants me to use passive form instead. However, I didn't find any reference that the use of active form is actually wrong and would really prefer to use the active form.

Is there any "official" rule in this regard? Both forms seem to be common in scientific publications, as I see it.

Edit: To clarify, english is not our first language. Thus, it's not an issue of "He who pays the piper may call the tune" (as indicated in the comments), but a question, if said active phrases are wrong.

Comment: The "official" rule is "He who pays the piper may call the tune". We've had discussions on the acceptability of the passive here before. I've seen articles on the acceptability of non-passive constructions in scientific English. Fred-down-the-road's boss probably dislikes the passive. This is a matter of style. But if I'm paying, I'm allowed to choose the style.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I feel there's a difference in meaning between "figure x depicts" and "as depicted in figure x".  e.g. "figure 5 depicts all side-effects that have been obeserved."  "As depicted in figure 5, side-effects have been more prevalent in women over 75".  To me, if we use "as depicted", an interpretation or conclusion is likely to follow in the same sentence. I'm not really sure, though. Am I wrong?

Comment: Just to add to what @EdwinAshworth says, the passive voice is a means to an end -- in some cases the only means, but not in this one.  I've not come across a journal style guide which says *every sentence* must be in the passive, which isn't to say they don't exist but some active-voice constructions are clearer while preserving the impersonal tone. I would (often) personally take your approach, as to recast in the passive is likely to come across as unnecessarily wordy.

Comment: @Centaurus, I think the key word in your comment is "likely".  You could easily have any of "Figure x shows that the model fits the data", "It is shown in Figure x that the model fits the data" and "As depicted in Figure x, the model fits the data".  The last -- in such a simple example -- does feel like it wants another clause, but it's not clearly lacking.

Comment: @ChrisH Thanks. As for your other comment, I agree with Edwin: if it's just a matter of style, whoever has the gold makes the rules.

Comment: @Centaurus  It is not a matter of the general use of active/passive voice. He is ok with active voice, but thinks a Figure can't show anything, i.e. the phrases are wrong. Do you have any reference, that this is just a matter of style? He can usually be convinced by solid arguments, so it's not "He who pays the piper may call the tune". English is not our first language.

Comment: Ah, now you've moved the goalposts. [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/show) gives these non-agentive senses of _show_:  **show** v.tr.
... 4.
a. To make evident or reveal (an emotion or condition, for example): (_showed displeasure at his remark_); _a carpet that shows wear._
b. To reveal (oneself) as in one's behavior or condition: _The old boat showed itself to be seaworthy._
c. To indicate; register: _The altimeter showed that the plane was descending._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, this is what I was hoping for. I think, I will use the dictionary entry together with some journal guidelines I found, that use above phrases as examples, to convince him.

Comment: You need to specify the _actual_ question. This is not directly about the 'use of the passive in scientific writing', but about 'whether the verbs _depict_ and _show_ may be used with inanimate subjects'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every publishing house has is a category of specific prohibitions populated by words and forms of usage whose only offense is to run afoul of the idiosyncrasies of one or more people who rank high enough in the organization to transform their personal language foibles into house policy. The proscribing of "Fig. X depicts" is exactly that type of rule.

Undoubtedly your boss is not the only person in the scientific or publishing universe who has parlayed a dislike of that particular usage into a house ban on its use, but the prohibition in question remains arbitrary and (in my experience as a longtime freelance copy editor) not especially widespread. If you ever move to another organization, the odds are good that you'll be able to use "Fig. [or perhaps *Figure*] X depicts" to your heart's content.